# Join on started room - Photon Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I wanted to "fake" persistant rooms. So I have a list of rooms with his names "room 1", "room 2", etc.

When the user clicks on one room I execute this:

```
PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom(roomName, new RoomOptions({MaxPlayers = 16, BroadcastPropsChangeToAll = true}, TypedLobby.Default);

PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("Game");
```

And when the user enters on game scene I instantiate his avatar:

```
GameObject myAvatar= PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerToSpawn.name, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

The user enters on room without problem, the avatar is instantiated without problem... but, only the first user can move his avatar.

Before, new players could move "a bit" the first instantiated avatar (and this avatar instantly back to his original position) until I put the line:

```
if (view.IsMine){
```

Now just the first player can move the first avatar.

But I still have the problem that only the first user/avatar that enters on room can move around the world. It's like all inputs affect just this first avatar.

I hope you could help me. Greetings.

Comment: The android-room tag doesn't appear to be at all relevant. Android Room is an object orientated wrapper around the SQLite database. As such I have removed the android-room tag. You may wish to check the tag(s) for their relevance before adding them in any further questions. You could also check out the following https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.